# Error linking to OpenCV after restructure of code

Tags: opencv, cmake

I've just reorganised my code (which worked before) and am now getting an error message when I run my executable: `The program can't start because opencv_core230d.dll is missing from your computer.` The error is accurate, I only have .lib library files for OpenCV, but it worked before and I don't think this should be a problem, should it?

An extract from the cmake file is:

```
FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED )

# Define LIBRARY and SRC_FILES to create my library
add_library(${LIBRARY} ${SRC_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${LIBRARY} ${OpenCV_LIBS} )

# Define appName and appFile to create application,
# and link to my library and OpenCV
add_executable(${appName} ${appFile})
target_link_libraries(${appName} ${LIBRARY} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Am I doing anything obviously wrong, or what else might cause this error?

---

**EDIT:** I've now reduced this problem to a minimal example. Inside one directory test I have two files: testApp.cpp and CMakeLists.txt as follows:

testApp.cpp

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::namedWindow("Test");
    cv::waitKey(0);
    cv::destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(test)

FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED )

add_executable(appName testApp.cpp)
target_link_libraries(appName ${OpenCV_LIBS})
message(STATUS "Linking testapp to: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
```

With the error as before: `opencv_highgui230d.dll is missing.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is a common problem which simply needed some more research. To fix, I just added the OpenCV/bin directory to the PATH environmental variable. Still not sure why it was working previously though...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the environment variable **PATH** does not point to the location where OpenCV's DLLs reside. Search inside OpenCV directories and if you can't find it you'll need to reinstall OpenCV.